# HashMap от объекта. Как получить значение поля объекта?

Tags: java, объекты, java-hashmap

Есть класс `WebController` в нём объявлена коллекция `private ConcurrentHashMap<String, User> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

Где `User` это класс со следующими полями:

```
public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

Допустим я положил в коллекцию `users.put(Alesha, new User(Alesha, Alesha@yandex.ru, 12345));`

Как мне из коллекции users теперь вытащить эмайл , т.е. второе поле?

В конечном итоге мне необходимо делать проверку, т.е. я буду получать значение с формы и это значение мне надо сравнить с полем `private String email` в коллекции users;

Распечатать мапу целиком я могу, а вот как взять отдельное значение Email, не понимаю(
`System.out.println("Печатаем мапу " + Arrays.asList(users));`

Comment: Через lombok я подключил следующие аннотации:
1)Getter
2)Setter
3)AllArgsConstructor
4)NoArgsConstructor
5)ToString


public class User {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элемент из `Map`-ы по ключу можно достать с помощью метода `get`, это даст объект типа `User`. Дальше из него нужно достать поле `email`.

```
 User user = users.get("Alesha");
 String userEmail = user.getEmail();
```

Чтоб это работало нужно, чтобы в классе `User` был опеределен `getter` для поля `email`:

```
class User {

    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
       return email;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: чтобы работало нужны ещё `equals` с `hashCode`

Comment: для данного примера - не нужны, т.к. тут нигде эти методы не используются. Тут поиск в `Map` делается по строке, а в `String` и `hashCode` и  `equals` определены.

Comment: ах, да, это же не ключ мапы, my bad

Comment: Чувак, я часа полтора убил, что бы родить решение этого вопроса
Спасибо, помог!

Answer (score 0):

С помощью рефлексии:

```java
User alesha = users.get("Alesha");
Field field = User.class.getDeclaredField("email");
field.setAccessible(true);
String email = field.get(alesha);
```